# Align controls in the center of screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have controls that I want to center them on the center of screen so I used the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:background="#DDDDDD">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_un"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10pt"
        android:textColor="#444444"

        android:layout_marginRight="9dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"

        android:text="User Name:"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_un"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_un"

        android:layout_alignTop="@id/tv_un"/>
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_pw"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10pt"
        android:textColor="#444444"

        android:layout_below="@id/tv_un"
        android:layout_marginRight="9dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"

        android:text="Password:"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_pw"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_pw"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/tv_pw"
        android:layout_below="@id/et_un"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dip"

        android:password="true"        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/et_pw"

        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dip"

        android:text="Login" />
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_error"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:textSize="7pt"

        android:layout_below="@id/btn_login"
        android:layout_marginRight="9dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
        android:textColor="#AA0000"

        android:text=""/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

but the output became as the following image

[image]

any idea how to center them regardless the orientation of the screen

Best regards

Comment: wrap all child views in another layout and apply the apptibute android:layout_centerInParent = "true" to that

Comment: @Akki I tried ur advice but doesn't work this is my updated code http://paste2.org/p/2031360

Answer (score 4, accepted):

edited your code

here it is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:background="#DDDDDD"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_un"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="User Name:"
            android:textColor="#444444"
            android:textSize="10pt" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_un"
            android:layout_width="150dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/tv_un"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_un"
            android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_pw"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_un"
            android:text="Password:"
            android:textColor="#444444"
            android:textSize="10pt" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_pw"
            android:layout_width="150dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/tv_pw"
            android:layout_below="@id/et_un"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_pw"
            android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
            android:password="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/et_pw"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:text="Login" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_error"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn_login"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="9dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#AA0000"
        android:textSize="7pt" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thansk a lot , you saved me twice

Answer (score 7):

Try `android:layout_centerInParent = "true"` This can solve your issue.. You can apply this attribute to any element you want to display in the center of the screen.

Comment: the whole controls be shifted to the right except the button this is my updated code http://paste2.org/p/2031352

Comment: It's shifting to the right because you've attributes such as `android:layout_marginRight` which gives an extra space.. If you remove `marginRight` and `marginLeft` attributes, I think you'll be good to go..

Comment: Thanks. Solved my problem in a single line of code.

Answer (score 2):

Set your `RelativeLayout` parameters: `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`  and `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Rest all of your XML seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" in both layout & layout-land folder xml files. Hope it helps.

P.s Please do not hardcode anything in xml file if you want the layout to fit all screen sizes

Comment: sorry but what do u mean by layout-land folder xml files

Comment: layout is for portrait mode, layout-land is for landscape mode. When you change the orientation of your screen, then the xml from layout-land is called(if defined). Else it will fetch from layout itself.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html go through this for more support

Comment: sorry I tried ur advice but still left horizontally aligned this is my updated code http://paste2.org/p/2031357

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `RelativeLayout` here. You also can use two `LinearLayouts` like the following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#DDDDDD"
    android:gravity="center" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <!-- here your textViews -->
        </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Important is the `android:layout_gravity="center"` in the nested `LinearLayout`.